# Three way frequency table to data frame matrix

Tags: r, dataframe

I am producing a frequency table of row percentages in **R** using the following method:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("Boy","Girl","Boy","Girl"))
colnames(df) <- "SEX"
df$GP <- c("A","A","B","B")
df$freq <- c(1,2,3,4)

tab <- as.data.frame.matrix(prop.table(table(df$GP, df$freq),1))
```

However, I would like to distinguish between frequencies by the variable "SEX". Is there a way to do this without splitting the dataframe by sex, creating two dataframes, one for boys and one for girls then merging together?

A three way frequency table `table(df$GP, df$freq, df$SEX)` cannot be coerced into a data frame matrix. Also using `exclude` such as `table(df$GP, df$freq, df$SEX, exclude="Boy")` results in the same problem.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but how to convert this to a data.frame.matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p_tabl <- prop.table(xtabs(freq~GP+SEX, data=df))
(as.data.frame(p_tabl))
```

Comment: Thanks, just need to specify row percentages by adding "1" -> `prop.table(xtabs(freq~SEX+GP, data=df),1)`.